# Mentions with a Custom Build

Tags: plugins, ckeditor5, mention

I have a custom CKEditor 5 build (which includes the Mention plugin). The Custom editor loads and works great. But I cannot get the mention plugin to work. The '@' symbol does not trigger the autocomplete. If I enable the plugins line of the config the editor will not load.

I am using anulgar.

```
import * as CustomEditor from '../libs/ckeditor5-build-custom/build/ckeditor';
import Mention from '../libs/ckeditor5-build-custom/build/ckeditor';

...

 editorConfig = {
    //plugins : [Mention],
    mention: {
        feeds: [
            {
                marker: '@',
                feed: ['@Barney', '@Lily', '@Marshall', '@Robin', '@Ted'],
                minimumCharacters: 1
            }
        ]
    }
```